# Cambiar el número predeterminado de filas de una tabla

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

Necesito es que cuando la pantalla este en una anchura inferior a 768px cambie el `data-page-lenght="15"` a uno `data-page-lenght="6"`

```js
var table = $('#tblDistribucionZonas').DataTable({
  scrollX: true,
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
  ],
  language: {
    "emptyTable": "No hay información",
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ Documentos",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 to 0 of 0 Documentos",
    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ total entradas)",
    "infoPostFix": "",
    "thousands": ",",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ Documentos",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "zeroRecords": "Sin resultados encontrados",
    "paginate": {
      "first": "Primero",
      "last": "Ultimo",
      "next": "Siguiente",
      "previous": "Anterior"
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.table-responsive {
  border: 0px;
}

.table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" data-page-length="15" width="100%" id="tblDistribucionZonas">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Puesto en el top</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Zona</th>
        <th>Venta</th>
        <th>Ingreso</th>
        <th>Iva</th>
        <th>Descuento</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>EJE CAF.PEREIRA</td>
        <td>775,731,615.04</td>
        <td>652,014,223.20</td>
        <td>123,717,391.84</td>
        <td>40,579,517.40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>06</td>
        <td>ZONA SUR (VALLE/CAUCA/NARIÑO)</td>
        <td>503,927,312.80</td>
        <td>423,468,330.43</td>
        <td>80,458,982.37</td>
        <td>25,358,819.59</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>05</td>
        <td>HUILA Y CAQUETA</td>
        <td>239,755,868.94</td>
        <td>201,475,520.14</td>
        <td>38,280,348.80</td>
        <td>8,067,695.74</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>04</td>
        <td>TOLIMA</td>
        <td>58,224,961.73</td>
        <td>48,928,539.28</td>
        <td>9,296,422.45</td>
        <td>2,681,183.20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>FUSA,MELGAR,GIRARDOT.</td>
        <td>10,817,773.14</td>
        <td>9,090,565.60</td>
        <td>1,727,207.54</td>
        <td>439,624.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>RICAURTE BOGOTA</td>
        <td>3,879,908.19</td>
        <td>3,260,427.04</td>
        <td>619,481.15</td>
        <td>116,095.95</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>DECORARCO CALI</td>
        <td>2,712,981.42</td>
        <td>2,279,816.31</td>
        <td>433,165.11</td>
        <td>291,163.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1,128,287.50</td>
        <td>948,140.75</td>
        <td>180,146.75</td>
        <td>99,302.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>08</td>
        <td>COSTA ATLANTICA</td>
        <td>758,934.95</td>
        <td>637,760.46</td>
        <td>121,174.49</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>07</td>
        <td>ANTIOQUIA</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.30</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>0.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: cuando hablas de data-page-lenght...te refieres a el numero de registros a mostrar ?

Comment: si me refiero solo a eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos podrias hacer algo como esto:

```js
  $('#example').DataTable();
  
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  if (height < 768) {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.page.len(1).draw();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Si te fijas defino mi datatable, luego obtengo el ancho y alto de mi pantalla(window), con esto mediante un if valido lo que deseo y establesco o defino el page-len del datatable.

Con:

```
table.page.len(1).draw();
```

defino el numero de registros a mostrar.

Espero te sirva y te ayude...!!

Comment: `var height = window.innerHeight;
  if (height > 768) {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.page.len(15).draw();
  }if (height < 768) {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    table.page.len(5).draw();
  }` trato de hacer eso y no me funciona

Comment: pero tienes que cambiar tu ID

Comment: eso hago y no funciona

Comment: revisa por consola si te tira algun error

Comment: viejo es que no hay errores cuando la pantalla esta menor a `width: 768` me tira los 5 y cuando estoy uno tamaño superior muestra los 15 pero lo que necesito es que lo cambie diatónicamente que si arrastro la pantalla cambiándole los tamaños de pantalla también cambie los registro pero solo funciona una vez

Comment: si, para que tome efecto los cambios debes refrescar la pantalla y asi detecte los cambios nuevos de pantalla y aplique el page-len

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90329/discussion-between-julian-andres-candamil-and-diego-avila).